# How to generate geometric or Gaussian distributed numbers from from uniform distributed numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, probability, probability-density

I want to generate geometric or Gaussian distributed random numbers without using "*geornd*" or "*randn*" functions present in MATLAB library. How can I generate random numbers with those distributions by using only the "*rand*" function used to generate uniformly distributed random numbers.
I want to do this because Uniform distribution is the most basic type distribution and any other distribution can be generated from this distribution. A small code example would be very helpfull..!!

Comment: I don't fully understand your rationale - the `geornd` function (and probably `randn` too) already uses the `rand` function to produce a result - so are you basically saying you just want to re-implement them yourself?

Comment: as @ jazzbassrob points out, if you have the stats toolbox check out the code for geornd: `edit geornd`

Comment: You may be interested in [this matlab page](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/normal-behavior.html) explaining the algorithm used for generating normal values (matlab changed the algorithm in v.6).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do this:

```
U = rand(1)
mu = 5;
sigma = 3;
N = mu + sigma * norminv(U,1,1)
```